# How to copy text contents in body to clipboard

Tags: javascript, clipboard, chromium-embedded

I need to copy all the text in my body to the clipboard,
here is what I've tried so far:

- selecting the text nodes and then the command `document.execCommand("copy")`
- selecting the text nodes and then using the keyboard dispatcher:

  ```
  $("body").contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3;}).select();
  document.body.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {bubbles: true, cancelable: false, key: "C", char: "C", ctrlKey: true}));
  ```

No errors pop up. I've read in the Chromium documentation that the copy command is disabled for security reasons. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying into clipboard will only work on a true user interaction. Without a true user interaction it will usually fail. I believe it's for security measures.
So hook it on a click event. Then I also suggest you use a library like [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) that sorts out trouble with different browsers and allows you to put in the html variety and plaintext copy.

If you'd use clipboard.js you could use code like this:

```
plaintext = "boo";
htmltext = "<strong>boo</strong>";
document.getElementById("copybutton").addEventListener('click', function() {
    clipboard.copy({ 
            'text/plain': plaintext,
            'text/html': htmltext
          }).then(
            function(){
                swal({
                    title: "Successfully copied",
                    text: "The thing has been put in your clipboard, happy pasting!",
                    type: "success",
                    closeOnConfirm:true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                    timer: 1200
                });
            },
            function(err){
                window.prompt("Something went wrong with automatically copying the data to clipboard.\nPlease press CTRC + C to copy the data",plaintext );
          });
    }
}
```